# how can i always have latest database backup

Tags: php, mysql, windows, xampp

Using PHP, HTML, Javascript and use XAMPP for windows. The system is only for local area connection.

I just wonder how can I always have the latest database backup if something happen like, the hardisk of the computer is broken or someone attack the system and drop the database, if something happen how can i have always the latest backup or what is the right thing to do.

Comment: Create a backup script and upload the output to a server. If you have a limited connection: Create a delta script or use log shipping & reconstruction on a database clone.

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen thanks, i will look for your suggested options :)

Comment: C'mon Norbert ... 'not a professional programmer' ... poor bloke probably has no clue what a 'delta' is.  How big is your database Comet?  Many tables?  How many records do you add per day do you think?

Comment: Hey comet, i suggest you to ask to dba.stackexchange.com, rather than stackoverflow.com

Comment: I thought the log shipping was pretty funny when I read it @Ragdata ... thought that might make comet fall out of his chair

Comment: @Drew - like telling someone who has just discovered fire that all their problems can be solved if only they bothered to get off their ass and split an atom or two :/

Comment: @MichaelAntonio i will thanks

Comment: @Ragdata i think atleast 5 records a day 15 tables

Comment: @White - the first link I posted in my answer should be plenty if you're up to doing it manually each day ... but check the others and see what you can handle.

Comment: @Ragdata i look at the last link and i think it also a good option and i think the backup destination is in a separate hard disk(slave) but i will read all of it soon thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In increasing level of complexity:

http://www.instructables.com/id/Backing-up-your-SQL-database-using-XAMPP-and-phpMy/

http://webcheatsheet.com/php/how_to_create_a_dump_of_mysql_database_in_one_click.php

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Automatic-DatabaseMySQL-backup-2139.php

Comment: thanks i will look for this its a really big help, im not in hurry, i just wanna learn about how can i do this :)